# MongoDB - Update text to Proper / title Case

Tags: mongodb

We have a large collection of documents with various text case when entered for their description
eg

```
Desc = 
'THE CAT"
or
"The Dog"
or
"the cow"
```

We want to make all consistent in Title (Or Proper case) where first letter of each word is upper and rest lower case.

```
"The Cat", "The Dog", "The Cow"
```

Looking for assistance in creating update query to do that on mass, rather than manual as data team is doing at present.

thanks

Comment: How much documents? If not so many, you can use a simple forEach and plain js code for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm for changing the title case below uses [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and the [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method which returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.
In your case, the pattern for the [**`replace()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method will be a `String` to be replaced by a new replacement and will be treated as a verbatim string.

First off, you need to lowercase and split the string before applying the [**`map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. Once you define a function that implements the conversion, you then need to iterate your collection to apply an update with this function. Use the **[`cursor.forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)** method on the cursor returned by **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** to do the loop and within the loop you can then run an update on each document using the **[`updateOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#db.collection.updateOne)** method.

For relatively small datasets, the whole operation can be described by the following

```
function titleCase(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(function(word) {
        return word.replace(word[0], word[0].toUpperCase());
    }).join(' ');
}

db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc){
    db.collection.updateOne(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        { "$set": { "desc": titleCase(doc.desc) } }
    );
});
```

---

For improved performance especially when dealing with huge datasets, take advantage of using a **[`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/)** API for updating the collection efficiently in bulk as you will be sending the operations to the server in batches (for example, say a batch size of 500). This gives you much better performance since you won't be sending every request to the server but just once in every 500 requests, thus making your updates more efficient and quicker.

The following demonstrates this approach, the first example uses the **[`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/)** API available in MongoDB versions >= 2.6 and < 3.2. It updates all the documents in the collection by transforming the title on the `desc` field using the above function.

*MongoDB versions >= 2.6 and < 3.2*:

```
function titleCase(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(function(word) {
        return word.replace(word[0], word[0].toUpperCase());
    }).join(' ');
}

var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0;

db.collection.find().forEach(function (doc) {    
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { "desc": titleCase(doc.desc) }
    });

    counter++;
    if (counter % 500 === 0) {
        // Execute per 500 operations
        bulk.execute(); 
        // re-initialize every 500 update statements
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
})
// Clean up remaining queue
if (counter % 500 !== 0) { bulk.execute(); }
```

The next example applies to the new MongoDB version 3.2 which has since [deprecated](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/release-notes/3.2/#mongo-shell-and-crud-api) the **[`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/)** API and provided a newer set of apis using **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite)**.

*MongoDB version 3.2 and greater*:

```
var ops = [],
    titleCase = function(str) {
        return str.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(function(word) {
            return word.replace(word[0], word[0].toUpperCase());
        }).join(' ');
    };
    
db.Books.find({
    "title": {
        "$exists": true,
        "$type": 2
    }
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": {
                "$set": { "title": titleCase(doc.title) }
            }
        }
    });

    if (ops.length === 500 ) {
        db.Books.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
})

if (ops.length > 0)  
    db.Books.bulkWrite(ops);
```

Comment: Thanks Chridam.  
Have tried but must be missing something.  I'm on MongoDb 3.2.10
My Collection is named "Books", so have replaced "collection" with "Books" in the scripts.

Using MongChef, pasted the script into Inellishell, ran and get:

2016-11-18T09:46:57.730+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: str is undefined :
titleCase@(shell):3:1
@(shell):6:20
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:488:1
@(shell):1:1

2016-11-18T09:46:57.736+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script @(shell):1:19

Comment: Which code did you use by the way? Also, make sure you have a `"desc"` field in the documents or replace the `"desc"` instances in the code with the actual **description** field in your schema else it will fail.

Comment: I used the code at bottom of your post for 3.2
And yes I changed the "desc" field to "title" in 2 spots which is the field name in my dB ...

Sorry.  now just getting:
TypeError: word[0] is undefined

Comment: Try to include a filter in your query to update only those documents with the `title` field and if it exists it should be a string, as in the updated code. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: They all have titles, everyone.  I filtered just for 1 ID and still get same error  
mmmm ?

Comment: Can you provide some sample documents from your collection and update your question please?

Comment: If I run the script with this filter for 1 document, then it works:
...
db.Meal.find( ({"_id": "knOIv8ZUUK"}) ).forEach(function(doc) 


If I use this filter below to check for title, then same issue in word[0] is undefined
...
db.Meal.find(({ "title": { $exists: true, $type: 2 } })).forEach(function(doc) {

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Initially you stated that your collection is named "Books" and now it's "Meal", which is which? Ok, can you provide say 3 documents from this query `db.Meal.find({ "title": { $exists: true, $type: 2 } }).limit(3)`?

Comment: Sorry Chridam.  2 different collections I need to do same thing on.  
I found the problem though.  If _title_ has 2 spaces in a row in it, then that caused a problem.  
I ran a prelim script to replace doubles with single spaces.  Now all works.
thanks for your (extended) time :)

Comment: @MarkM No worries, glad I could be of help